# Is there any benefit to have an async method call if this is the last call in the enclosing method?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

I have an API method like this:

```
[HttpGet("NumberOnStock")]
public async Task<int> NumberOnStock([FromQuery] Guid productId)
{
    return await _context.Products.Where(product => product.Id == productId).CountAsync();
}
```

Is there any benefit to have this method use `CountAsync()` instead of `Count()` if it is just the only and last call within `NumberOnStock` method?

Comment: Yes, it will release a thread to service other concurrent HTTP requests. `Count` will block until the database responds.

Comment: Could you include in the question an example of using `Count()`?

Comment: Why do you think whether or not it's the last call somehow affects whether to use Count or CountAsync?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, assuming you are using a database with actual async support, using `CountAsync()` instead of `Count()` will free the thread to process other requests if run on a server. Or avoid blocking the UI thread if used in a UI application. This might not be super important for counting the number of rows, since this should return fairly quickly even using the blocking version in most cases. But using async-version of calls is generally a good practice.

If you are using `CountAsync()` you do not need to make use await or mark the method async. If you do not need to process the result in any way you can just return the task directly.

Comment: Does leaving out await let's the result be awaited later? What does it change?

Comment: @Yoda `async` instructs the compiler to rewrite the method , it is only needed when you need the result. And you can await any task, how that task was created is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

By just returning the `Task<int>` rather than `await`ing it you avoid allocating the state machine that goes with the `await`.

As for whether you should use `Count` or `CountAsync`, a call to `Count` will block the current thread whilst the count is performed, whereas the call to `CountAsync` will allow calling thread to me be made available to process other requests, improving overall application performance.

In summary, use `CountAsync` and don't bother with `await`:

```
[HttpGet("NumberOnStock")]
public Task<int> NumberOnStock([FromQuery] Guid productId)
{
    return _context.Products.Where(product => product.Id == productId).CountAsync();
}
```

Comment: The question was about `CountAsync` vs `Count`. The use of async / await keywords are a side issue.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay - the body of the question asks one thing, but the title of the question asks another.

Comment: Why shouldn't I bother with `await`?

Comment: @Yoda Calling `await` will allocate the `async/await` state machine in your function, so by not doing the `await` you can avoid the allocation.

Comment: It does change exception handling semantics though, so you must take that into consideration.